# IE Form redirecting to action

Tags: forms

I have the following simple form:

```
<form id="MyForm" action="../webformmailer.php" method="post" >
<input type="hidden" name="subject" value="Submission" />
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="../sandbox/123/thanks.html" />
<input type="text" size="20" name="FirstName" />
<input type="text" size="20" name="LastName" />
<input type="text" size="20" name="email" />
<select name="comment">
<option value="yes">Yes</option>
<option value="no">No</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>      
</form>
```

I am redirecting users to a simple 'thanks.html' page after they submit their information. This works well in all browsers except IE 8, which redirects users to the webformmailer.php or the action of the form.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Inside your action script, process the request and then redirect to thanks.html:

```
header('Location: ../sandbox/123/thanks.html');
```

**Update:** since you don't have control over the action script, and all other browsers work exception IE8, then the problem must be in the way IE8 sends data to the server. Try set `enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` and see if it works.

Comment: webformmailer.php is a file provided by my host and I cannot edit it!

Comment: @user890803: so the provider instructs you to put a hidden field for the redirect url inside your form and you don't know how the redirect actually happens?

Comment: @user890803: then the problem might be from the way IE 8 encode(escape) the redirect url sent to the server.